# Baby Rudin Theorem 2.23 — How do we know a limit point exists for the complement of an open set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In *Principles*, Rudin states the following in his proof of Theorem 2.23 (that within a metric space, a set $E$ is open iff its complement is closed):

> Suppose $E$ is open. Let $x$ be a limit point of $E^c \dots$

How do we know such a limit point exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t know that it exists. But if there is no limit point for $E^c$, then it is closed, because it contains all its limit points, which is $\varnothing$.

Comment: If anything, the *set* of its limit points is $\emptyset$. If there are no limit points, then $E^c$ is closed because it contains all its limit points, period.